# Is XMLHTTP's responsebody working asynchronously in VB6?

Tags: vb6, stream, xmlhttprequest

We have a SSRS integrated sharepoint server. I am trying to get a report exported as PDF from it.

(I had to do like this, because my url is too long. I would rather use Shell command to do like this, although this looks like a better solution.)

Here'is my code:

```
Dim request as New XMLHTTP
Dim oStream as New Stream
Dim aBunchOfMiliseconds as Long

Dim fileLocation as String
Dim reportUrl as String

aBunchOfMiliseconds = 500

reportUrl = "http://www.mySharepointDomain.com/_vti_bin/ReportServer?http://www.mySharepointDomain.com/sites/AFolderHere/OOAnotherFolder/BlaBlaReportFolder/FolderFolder/AhTheLastOne/AtLeastMyReportFile.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=true&rs:Format=PDF&Parameter1=ABC  &Parameter2=1&Parameter3=1&TheLastParameter=IllBeDamned&rs%3aParameterLanguage=ln-LN"


request.Open "GET", reportUrl
request.setRequestHeader "WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM" 'For impersonation
request.Send 'Go get it Bruce

If request.Status = 200 Then 'Are you successful?

  oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
  oStream.Open

  oStream.Write request.responseBody 'Here's the problematic part
  Sleep(aBunchOfMiliseconds) 'If I don't do this, file will be corrupted

  oStream.SaveToFile fileLocation, adSaveCreateOverWrite

  oStream.Close


End If


Set oStream = Nothing
Set request = Nothing
```

If I comment out the "Sleep" line, I will have a corrupted file that can not open. This code works fine but I found it ridiculus to use "Sleep" there.

Is there any way me to understand that the data copy operation is completed?

Answer (score 1):

Oh I get it.

I've missed to say that "this is not an async call".

```
request.Open "GET", reportUrl, False
```